# React как передать событие в соседний компонент

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hook

Мне нужно сделать клик в одном компоненте и по этому клику вызвать функцию в соседнем . Какой самый простой способ?

Я сделал так.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-l5beyi
Но мне кажется можно сделать намного проще.  Реакт для меня нов, и эта конструкция выглядит странно...

Мои два компонента нужно передать событие(клик) из ComponentFirst в ComponentSecind  и там вызывть функцию

```
const App = () => {
const [isAdded, setIsAdded] = useState(false);

function handleClick(status) {
    setIsAdded(status)
}

return (
    <div>
        <ComponentFirst
            HandleClick={handleClick}
        />
        <ComponentSecond
            isAdded={isAdded}
            handleCreate={handleClick}
        />
    </div>
);
```

}

```
const ComponentFirst = ({HandleClick}) => { 
return (
  <button
           onClick={HandleClick}
  >button</button>
)
```

}

```
const ComponentSecond = (props) => {
let {isAdded, handleCreate} = props;
const result = () => {
    alert('work')
    console.log('work')
}

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isAdded) {
        result()
        handleCreate(false);
    }
}, [isAdded, handleCreate]);

return (
    <></>
)
```

}

Comment: Сама идея кликать в одном, а функцию запускать в другом компоненте уже сама по себе странная... Мне кажется все это притянуто за уши. Что хоть та функция будет делать?

Answer (score 0):

А можно по-подробнее? Кажется, Вы избрали не самый оптимальный путь. Если у вас будет в функции `result` производиться получение данных, то сам по себе, способ это сделать - очень странный. Сам не профи, но как по-мне, лучше юзать `react-redux`, или `Context` самого `React`. Данные не стоит хранить в состояниях. Гораздо проще законнектить их как пропсы, а событиями прибить их к Redux. Но, повторюсь, - не профи, могу и ошибаться.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идёт о событие в дочернем компоненте которое должно обновлять состояние в родителя, то самый простой способ передать в дочерний компонент колбэк который будет принимать нужные значения и основываясь на них делать изменения уже в родительском компоненте